# SQL query to find missing rows

Tags: sql

I have two tables A and B

```
A -> A_ID
     net_ID

B-> B_ID
    net_ID
```

these tables are related by net_ID

I have to find all the net_ID's which are missing in table B from that of A.

I have below query

```
select net_ID from A where net_ID not in (select net_ID from B);
```

Will this work?

Comment: why don't you try it out? :)

Comment: It won't work if b.net_ID is nullable!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use the [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator:

```
SELECT net_ID FROM A
EXCEPT 
SELECT net_ID FROM B
```

From MSDN:

> EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not
>   also found on the right query.

Which is exactly what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      A.*
FROM        A
LEFT JOIN   B On A.net_ID = B.net_ID
WHERE       B.net_ID is NULL
```